# QSettings::status() returns empty QString in logText, but returns string with "0" in QDebug()

Tags: qt

I have following class constructor:

```
UeSettings::UeSettings(QObject *parent,
                       const QString& settingsFile)
    : QObject(parent),
      m_ueSettingsFile(settingsFile)
{
    QString logText=QString();

    this->ueSetServerAddress(QString());
    this->ueSetServerPort(QString());
    this->ueSetDatabaseName(QString());
    this->ueSetDatabaseUsername(QString());
    this->ueSetDatabasePassword(QString());
    this->ueSetSettingsData(new QSettings(this->ueSettingsFile(),
                                          QSettings::IniFormat,
                                          this));

    connect(this,
            SIGNAL(ueSignalEventInfoAdded(QString)),
            parent,
            SLOT(ueSlotEventInfoAdded(QString)));

    logText=tr("[INFO]").append(" ")
                        .append(QDateTime::currentDateTime().toString("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz"))
                        .append(" ")
                        .append(tr("Config file status ")
                        .append(this->ueSettingsData()->fileName())
                        .append(": ")
                        .append(this->ueSettingsData()->status()));

    emit this->ueSignalEventInfoAdded(logText);

    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO
             << this->ueSettingsData()->status();
}   // constructor
```

Now, why do I get empty `QString` from `QSettings::status` in line building `logText` and why do I get `0` (which is ok, since this value means `QSettings::NoError`) in `qDebug()` line?

Comment: Try `.append(QString::number(this->ueSettingsData()->status()))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the problem with

```
.append(QString::number(this->ueSettingsData()->status()));
```

as user **Sajmplus** has given hint.